# I can't figure if these 2 series are convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have 2 series. The first one is: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ln(n)}{n (n+1)^\frac{1}{2}}$$ I've tried to compare it with some kind of harmonic series but I can't find the ideal one. My problem is mainly with the $ln(n)$. At the end I have something like: $\frac{ln(n)}{n(n+1)^\frac{1}{2}} > \frac{ln(n)}{2n^2}$ but I don't know if I can conclude that $\frac{ln(n)}{2n^2}$ is divergent. $$$$$$$$

I also have this other series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{ln(n)^\frac{1}{n}}$$ The first thing I did was to take the nth root but I can't because the denominator would end up being $ln(n)^\frac{1}{n^2}$ , and I got really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, it feels tempting to compare the first series to $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{1.5}}$. We know that $\ln(n)$ grows *very slowly*, so I would bet that the numerator $\ln(n)$ does not prevent this series from converging.

Pursuing this line of thought, I would conjecture that $\ln(n)$ grows more slowly than $n^s$ for any $s > 0$, and in particular for, say, $s = 1/4$. If we can show this is true, then we can compare $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{1.5}}$ with the series $\sum \frac{n^{.25}}{n^{1.5}}$, which we know converges.

Now we just need to check that $\ln(n)$ grows more slowly than $n^{1/4}$. By l'Hospital's rule, 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{1/4}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1/x}{\frac14 x^{-\frac34}} = 0.
$$

This shows that $\ln(x) < x^{1/4}$ for sufficiently large values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

In the second problem, consider
$$(\ln x)^{1/x}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln\ln x}{x}\right).$$
Now, for $x\ge e$,
$$0=\frac{\ln\ln e}x\le\frac{\ln\ln x}{x}\le\frac{\ln x}x$$
as $\ln x\le x$. But $(\ln x)/x\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, so hat
$(\ln x)^{1/x}\to1$ as $x\to\infty$. Your second series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 1$ and $r > 0$.  Then consider the function $$f(r,n) = n^{-r} \log n.$$  We search for critical points in the domain of $f$ satisfying $$0 = \frac{df}{dn} = -n^{-(r+1)} (r \log n - 1),$$ consequently $n = e^{1/r}$ is the only such critical point, and $f''(e^{1/r}) = -re^{-(1+2/r)} < 0$.  Therefore, the maximum value attained for $f$ is $$f(r, e^{1/r}) = (er)^{-1},$$ from which it follows that whenever $r > 1/e$, then $f(r,n) < 1$ on $n \in [1, \infty)$ and we conclude $$\log n < n^r.$$  We then can apply the comparison test directly to the summand, say with the choice $r = 2/5 > 1/e$:
$$\frac{\log n}{n (n+1)^{1/2}} < \frac{n^{2/5}}{n(n+1)^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{n^{3/5}(n+1)^{1/2}} < \frac{1}{n^{3/5}n^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{n^{11/10}}.$$  But since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{11/10}}$$ converges, the original sum is also convergent.